# Selecting Polygon Features in QGIS Lisboa

Tags: qgis, polygon

I want to select and save as a separate shape file, a smaller section (polygon) from a whole island country which includes both land and shallow habitat coastal features (like coral reefs) and when I draw and select a polygon, the indicated yellow selected area includes areas outside of the polygon I have drawn.

What am I doing wrong so that I can select polygons that are subsections of larger maps without including these 'outside' areas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  I am having trouble picturing what you are describing in words so will +1 your question to hopefully give you enough reputation to edit your Question so that it includes a graphic.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your data is using Multipolygons.

Switch the layer to Editing mode , then try `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Multipart to singleparts`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not fix the problem unfortunately. Is there a 'Cut' tool in QGIS like in ArcView?

Comment: Actually, just saw there is a cutting tool in the Digitising plugin but I cannot activate it (its in grey mode). How can I make it active?

Comment: To activate the icon, you have to select a feature with the `Select features Tool`. But this will delete the whole feature.